# LINQ distinct entries

Tags: linq

I have a database that contains appointments.  there can be multiple appointments scheduled for the same time.  I would like to retrieve a list of available appointment times that does not include duplicate times.

EDIT

for instance I could have in my database

```
REQUEST_ID    REQUESTER_ID   APPOINTMENT_TIME
     1             0        30-JUN-13 03.30.00 AM
     2             1        30-JUN-13 03.30.00 AM
     3             0        30-JUN-13 03.30.00 AM
     4             0        30-JUN-13 03.30.00 AM
     5             3        30-JUN-13 03.35.00 AM
     6             0        30-JUN-13 03.45.00 AM
     7             0        30-JUN-13 03.45.00 AM
```

I would want returned

```
REQUEST_ID    REQUESTER_ID   APPOINTMENT_TIME
     1             0        30-JUN-13 03.30.00 AM
     6             0        30-JUN-13 03.45.00 AM
```

END EDIT

this query returns all of the available appointment slots

```
var data =
    (from a in db.FLU_SHOT
      where a.REQUESTER_ID == 0
      select a).ToArray();
```

this query only returns times and I lose the rest of the information from the database

```
var times =
   (from a in data
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(a.APPOINTMENT_TIME)
    select a.APPOINTMENT_TIME).Distinct().ToArray();
```

this query returns the same information as my first query

```
var times =
   (from a in data
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(a.APPOINTMENT_TIME)
    select a).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first and your second and third queries vary **wildly**.

Comment: the second and third one run after the first one in an attempt to further breakdown the data.   I am sharing what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s `DistinctBy`:

```
var times =
   (from a in data
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(a.APPOINTMENT_TIME)
    select a).DistinctBy(a => a.APPOINTMENT_TIME).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, you could either use a rudimentary `GroupBy` approach:

```
var times =
   (from a in data
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(a.APPOINTMENT_TIME)
    select a).GroupBy(a => a.APPOINTMENT_TIME).Select(g => g.First()).ToArray();
```

or my custom lambda equality comparer (this is faster than the `GroupBy`, but slower than `DistinctBy` as Servy has pointed out many times):

```
var times =
   (from a in data
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(a.APPOINTMENT_TIME)
    select a).Distinct(PropertyEqualityComparer.GetNew(a => a.APPOINTMENT_TIME))
             .ToArray();
```

Here's the code for it:

```
public class PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty> 
    : IEqualityComparer<TObject>
{
    Func<TObject, TProperty> _selector;
    IEqualityComparer<TProperty> _internalComparer;
    public PropertyEqualityComparer(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> innerEqualityComparer = null)
    {
        _selector = propertySelector;
        _internalComparer = innerEqualityComparer;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(TObject obj)
    {
        return _selector(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool Equals(TObject x, TObject y)
    {
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer = 
            _internalComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default;
        return comparer.Equals(_selector(x), _selector(y));
    }
}
//and here's a class to help instantiate it with anonymous objects
public static class PropertyEqualityComparer
{
    public static PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
        GetNew<TObject, TProperty>(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector)
    { 
        return new PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
            (propertySelector);
    }
    public static PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
        GetNew<TObject, TProperty>
        (Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector, 
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer)
    { 
        return new PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
            (propertySelector, comparer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like MoreLinq is for Linq to Objects. His question states he's querying a database. If he attempts to use this method, all records will be pulled in from the database and the `DistictBy` operation will be done in-memory. Not very efficient.

Comment: @BrianBall He's already pulled the records (see the first query).

Comment: Which I would generally recommend he not do unless he needs all of the records.

Comment: @Brian I agree, but he's done it so I might as well take advantage of it.

Comment: thanks for your help.   I went with the groupby.   If there is a more efficient way to retrieve what I am looking for without pulling all the records first, I would be interested in that.  I am new to using LINQ.

Comment: @Mike As far as I know, no there isn't.

Comment: ok, no big deal, there will never be enough entries to noticeably affect performance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GroupBy`:

```
var times = data.GroupBy(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d.APPOINTMENT_TIME))
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Was going to say GroupBy too but spent too long writing my query. Partly because my query was overly complciated compared to yours (in the Select).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I'm trying to accomplish something with LINQ (that ultimately queries a database), and the answer isn't obvious, I write the SQL statement first, then I figure out how to translate that into LINQ.

If you can't figure out how to do the translation, then you can either find a tool online to help, or you can turn your query into a stored proc or UDF and call it from the data context.

In moderately to highly complicated queries, it's almost always better to write it by hand. Most likely, whatever LINQ spits out won't be very optimized for your specific scenario. You can usually coax LINQ into outputting the query you want, but by then you've wasted a lot of valuable time that could have bee spent doing something else more productive.

EDIT:
To answer your question more directly, it looks like you're mainly interested in the APPOINTMENT_TIMEs. In that case, do a group by on that column, then you can loop through each group and get the time(s).